# How to get the primary key of a specific row that you have queried (Android Studio SQLite)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Here's my function. I want to know a way to get the primary key of the row that will match the query.
This function is used check whether an account is present already in the database by matching the user input username and password to the col_2 (usernames in the database) and col_3 (passwords in the database). Once a match is found, I want to know a way to get the primary key of that row.

```
public Boolean checkUser(String username, String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String selection = COL_2 + "=?" + " and " + COL_3 + "=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {username, password};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        if (count > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer this: https://www.javatpoint.com/android-sqlite-tutorial  You will understand basics of SQLite

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar like this:

```
long rowId = -1;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   rowId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(PRIMARY_KEY));
}
```

Replace

```
   PRIMARY_KEY
```

with your name of the primary key row. 
Don't forget to adapt the query to get the primary key too in the cursor.